How much taxes would I have to pay if I sold my startup in cash?
If I sold my tech startup to a large entity for $1 Billion dollars in cash. How much is Uncle Sam getting?

A lot. Or nothing. If you're selling a startup for $1B, I'm sure you can afford an accountant.

Definitely not a personal finance question, so offtopic.


If I sold my tech startup to a large entity for $1 Billion dollars in
cash. How much is Uncle Sam getting?

Selling a business is complex transaction. They have assets and liabilities. They have capital items that have been partially depreciated. They have investors and maybe even people that have loaned them money.
All of those things factor into the business and the personal tax picture. Knowing the sale price tells you nothing.
Here is a simpler example. If person sells their house for $1,000,000 they may owe a lot in capital gains taxes, or nothing. It depends on their cost basis. If they bought it decades ago for $50,000 they will have a big tax bill. If they bought it a few years ago for $1,100,000 they lost money, so they owe nothing.
